# NotifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked event and mouse buttons

Tags: c#, vb.net, mouseevent, notifyicon, balloon

I've got a NotifyIcon that signals downloadable application updates. I want the download page to open on a Left Click on the NotifyIcon and on a Left Click on the NotifyIcon balloon (on screen for 10 seconds).

However, when I handle the BalloonTipClicked event I can't figure out if it was a Left or a Right click. Thus, while the balloon is still on screen and the user Right clicks on the icon, I get both the popup menu **and** the download page opening.

How do I detect the Right mouse button was used?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to distinguish left or right mouse button in this case. See a similar question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/6af876d8-543e-409a-9d6e-c7dd8fb5efc7

Comment: Well, thanks I suppose. Bit of a let-down though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try testing the mouse state with code like this:

```
    private void notifyIcon1_BalloonTipClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if ((Control.MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Right) == MouseButtons.Right)
            MessageBox.Show("Right button clicked");
    }
```

I cannot test it on my machine with Win7, right-clicking the balloon just dismisses it and displays the context menu of the taskbar.  Which is your ultimate nemesis I'd say.

Comment: Ahh of course. The Clicked event is raised /before/ the mouse button state goes back to none. Thanks!